# How to ignore cell when the file path is blank

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a code on my excel worksheet.
The purpose I create the worksheet is to copy selected data from multiple file in a folder.

I wish to know whether is there any possible that I can ignore the blank cell when the file path is blank?

I have my code here but when the file path is blank, it will show Run-time error '1004': Sorry, we couldn't find . Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?

Here will be my code :

```
Option Explicit

Sub FetchData()

Dim shDestin As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set shDestin = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

CopyFileContent Range("B11").Value & shDestin.Range("A1").Value, _
                shDestin, 11

CopyFileContent Range("B12").Value & shDestin.Range("A1").Value, _
                shDestin, 12



End Sub


Sub CopyFileContent(filePath As String, destSheet As Worksheet, destRow As Long)

Dim wbSource As Workbook, shSource As Worksheet, rngDest As Range

Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filePath)
Set shSource = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1")

Set rngDest = destSheet.Cells(destRow, 5).Resize(1, 9)

'ni
rngDest.Value = shSource.Range("C2:K2").Value
rngDest.Value = shSource.Range("C2:K2").Value
'au
rngDest.Offset(0, 9).Value = shSource.Range("C3:K3").Value
'pd
rngDest.Offset(0, 18).Value = shSource.Range("C4:K4").Value

wbSource.Close False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you make the call to the function `CopyFileContent` you need to make sure that the cells that you get the value from are not empty.

You can use the function `IsEmpty()` to check whether the cell is empty or not.

Edit: Based upon the comments of the questioner the actual check should be like this:

```
If (not IsEmpty(Range("B12").Value) Then
  CopyFileContent Range("B12").Value & shDestin.Range("A1").Value, _
                  shDestin, 12
EndIF
```

In this case the function will only be executed when cell B12 is not empty.

Comment: I meant that if
    CopyFileContent Range("B12").Value & shDestin.Range("A1").Value, _
                shDestin, 12

is empty, than it will not perform the following CopyFileContent function...

Comment: Do you mean that either cell B12 or cell A1 is empty in shDestin?

Comment: it should be cell B12 is empty. B12 actually is the file path